# How do you say "create a poll"?

Tags: phrase-requests

As *poll*, I am thinking about a place/thing where each person can cast one vote for one choice between several choices. I used to say *krei voĉdonujon*, but it is not a common way to say it, and it refers to the container, not the event.

Comment: Eble *voĉdonado*?

Comment: don't you mean a "polling station" a "poll" is "the process of voting in an election." it is never the place you go to vote.

Comment: You can "take", "run", or "call for" a "poll". You can go to the "polls" (note the "s"), but you can't go to the "poll".  You can go to "poll" (verb form) people....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[John Wells's dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) suggests the following:

> **poll** balot-i, -ado; ricevi (multajn, malmultajn) voĉojn; (opini-)sondado, enketo

I think the final pair of translations have the meaning you want, so either one of these could work:

> Krei enketon
>
> Opinisondi

Comment: Isn't *enketo* more like a questionaire, with many questions that you need to answer?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Hmm, I don't know. PIV just says “metoda esploro pri ia okazaĵo aŭ opinio”. I guess you can methodically research an opinion with just one question, right?

Comment: Hmm, maybe my understanding is coming from the way *анкета [anketa]* is used in my native Bulgarian. Or maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly? According to ReVo, *enketo* = (en) inquiry, investigation, survey. To me this is different than a poll but I'm not a native English speaker, so I may be wrong.

Comment: On a decision in a group "Lasu nin baloti (voĉdoni) pri tio" ([nl] afstemmen, [de] abstimmen)

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev For what it's worth, "enketo" was the word always used on Lernu for forum polls, back when that feature was available.

Comment: @kristan I came to make the same observation. "enketo" is automatically the word I think of for "poll", because of Lernu.

Answer (score 4):

There's the root *balot-* for election like polls which have a binding result to something.

If you only want to find out peoples opinion for your own interest, use the root *enket-*